# Selenium get all inner text of an element with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
<div class="test"> <span>
        <div>TEXT </div>
    </span>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li> <span>Other text</span>
TEST1</li>
            <li>TEST2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get all of the inner text of the div with test class ? Ideally I would like to have an array of string , something like : ["TEXT","Other text","TEST1","TEST2"].

Comment: I researched it a bit more , I can actually get all of the text with this Xpath expression : ` //*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "test")]/descendant::*/text() ` . The problem is when I use findElements , I get an error saying that the results are not WebElements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
 List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='test']"));
 for(WebElement element: list){
    //print text if text not empty
    String text = element.getText();
    if(!text.isEmpty){
      S.O.P("Result :"+text);
    }
 }
```

Comment: `browser.driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "test")]')).then(function (result) {
                    result.forEach(function(entry) {
                        entry.getText().then(function (value) {
                            console.log(value);
                        })
                    });
                });`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the webdriver methods directly, `protractor` has a convenient abstraction around `findElements()` - `element.all()`. [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) would help to get a promise resolving into an array of texts:

```
var texts = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='test']//*")).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});

expect(texts).toEqual(["TEXT", "Other text", "TEST1", "TEST2"]);
```